# scripts for renaming files

Tags: shell, batch-file, scripting

I have a folder full of samples (.wav) and I need to rename all of them so that they are like this: sound (1).wav, sound (2).wav etc. there are about 500 sounds in there so a batch or script to do so would be great. I have no experience writing scripts so could somebody help me please?

Comment: Do you need a script to rename the 500 songs only once? If it is so, you can just use the windows rename command.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a batch file inside the folder and executing it.
The steps are as follows:

1) Open notepad type the following:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.wav') do (
  ren "%%i" "sound (!a!).wav" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

2) Save the file with the extension .bat in the folder which contains the files that needs to be renamed.

3) Double click the file to run.

4) All the files will be renamed.

This will work in **Windows**.